# $(window).scroll(...) is running even if the template is destroyed in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor, meteorite

I have two separate template and in both template(rendered) i am doing **$(window).scroll()** but however go to one template another, the **$(window).scroll()** is running from both, previous as well as current template.

Code Snippets as below:

dashboard1.js

```
Template.dashboard1.rendered = function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log('dashboard1 scroll');
        //... doing pagination and sticky element for dashboard1
    });
}

Template.dashboard1.destroyed = function(){
    console.log('dashboard1 destroyed');
}
```

dashboard2.js

```
Template.dashboard2.rendered = function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log('dashboard2 scroll');
        //... doing pagination and sticky element for dashboard2
    });
}

Template.dashboard2.destroyed = function(){
    console.log('dashboard2 destroyed');
}
```

Console:

```
dashboard1 destroyed
dashboard2 scroll
dashboard1 scroll
dashboard2 scroll
dashboard1 scroll
dashboard2 scroll
```

But if i refresh the browser, then it is coming from current template only.

Why this is happening any idea? what is the way to fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Destroying a template in Meteor will perform internal cleanup regarding the template rendering engine (`Blaze`) and it will unregister events declared via template event maps, but it won't unregister global window events Meteor is not aware of.

After registering a custom global event in the `onRendered` lifecycle event callback using `$.on`, you'll need to unregister it in the `onDestroyed` callback using `$.off`.

You can use this pattern to register and unregister handlers :

```
Template.dashboard1.onRendered(function(){
  this.scrollHandler = function(){
    // you can use the this keyword here to reference the template instance
    console.log("dashboard1 scroll");
    //... doing pagination and sticky element for dashboard1
  }.bind(this);
  $(window).on("scroll" ,this.scrollHandler);
});

Template.dashboard1.onDestroyed(function(){
  $(window).off("scroll", this.scrollHandler);
  console.log("dashboard1 destroyed");
});
```

By attaching a this-bound function as a property of the template instance, you can perform template instance specific logic inside the event handler.

Comment: cheers!! got it and it works fine. i have one more query to you...which one is better **$(window).off('scroll')** or **$(window).unbind('scroll')** ??

Comment: Use `$.on` and `$.off`, `$.bind` and `$.unbind` are deprecated and may be removed in future versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove your listener manually when template is destroyed.

```
var scrollHandler = function() {
  console.log('dashboard1 scroll');
}

Template.dashboard1.rendered = function() {
  $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
}

Template.dashboard1.destroyed = function() {
  $(window).off("scroll", scrollHandler);
  console.log('dashboard1 destroyed');
}
```